# Call to undefined function Database\Seeders\factory()

Tags: laravel, factory, seed

I have that error, since i create a UserFactory and in my UserTableSeeder add this line `factory(App\User::class,10)->create();` here a picture

In my UserTableSeeder i replace `factory(App\User::class,10)->create();`   by this `\App\Models\User::factory()->count(10)->create();`
In my UserFactory i replace `'username' => $faker->name,` by this`'username' => $this->faker->text(10)` no results
Thank you for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbM2V.png)

Comment: Can you share also your User model ? I want to know if your model are using HasFactory trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model `User.php`

```php
namespace App\Models; // App instead app
// ...
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
// ...

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
//...
}
```

In your seeder:

```
\App\Models\User::factory(10)->create([
    // Some optional static fields
    'role' => 'user',
    ]);
```

Additionally, you are confused about using `app` instead `App` for your namespace declaration because the app folder is in lowercase, but you need to see `composer.json` file and you will find this lines:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
```

The app folder is parsed as `App` namespace, so you need allways use `namespace App\...` in in declarations, and `\App` or `App` in the uses.

Comment: Hello thank you, so first sorry i just check my model User.php and i didn't have, i add them now. Then, i have an other error like  Class "App\Models\User" not found at database\seeders\UsersTableSeeder.php:28. So ifer check on internet i add this use App\Models\User; in UsersTableSeeder but without results same error i still have (see my new capture if need)

Comment: @lara this is because your User model (idk why) are not in Models folder. I dont know what Laravel version are you running. Try it with `App\User::factory(...)`

Comment: well i put all my models in one model folder and i had many errors but i correct all of them and it's fine. Then i even change my code (UserFactory), and all my App to app uppercase etc etc but i still have the same error (check my new picture please) and thank you (ps: i check my version of Laravel 11.0.7)

Comment: You moved your Models to Models folder, now you need change the namespace at the top of all your models. You now have `namespace app;` Your namespace must be `namespace App\Models;`

Comment: i did and it words, thank you so much ! By the way for those who have the same pb, after  that i still have en error like undefined function and i just changed this 'username' => $faker->name, into this 'username' => $this->faker->name, and it works, thank you @edpmath

Comment: Your welcome. Please see the new update in the answer so you understand why to use `App` instead of `app`